# Wave equation ON a sphere

Tags: waves, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, differential-equations

I was thinking of those videos of football players in slow motion, where they hit the ball, and a wave propagates all along it.

I know you can describe a wave in different kinds of coordinates, with:
$$
\partial^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\phi=0
$$
But, from what I understand, this equation can describe a sacalar field, vector field, etc. in which a wave is propagating. But the domain is space itself. This wave isn't propagating through an object, for example, an sphere.

How I even describe a wave propagating and deformations though any kind of object? Does
$$
\partial^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\phi=0
$$
still holds?

Comment: Have you encountered [Spherical harmonics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics) before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to [re-express the wave equation in spherical coordinates](https://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/%7Epaboyle/Teaching/PhysicalMaths/Notes_2010/notes_2010_part3.pdf) for a constant $r$. In spherical coordinates the Laplacian is
$$\nabla^2 u = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2} + \frac{2}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r^2 \sin \theta}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(\sin\theta \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\right)+\frac{1}{\sin \theta}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \phi^2}\right].$$
If we set $r=1$ we get
$$\nabla^2 u = \frac{1}{\sin \theta}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(\sin\theta \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\right)+\frac{1}{\sin \theta}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \phi^2}\right].$$

So the wave equation $$\nabla^2 u = \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}$$ becomes

$$ \frac{1}{\sin \theta}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(\sin\theta \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\right)+\frac{1}{\sin \theta}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \phi^2}\right]= \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}.$$

This can be solved in terms of spherical harmonics using separation of variables.

Now if you want to describe the wobbles of a deformable object things get a bit more complex, since now it is no longer exactly following the wave equation (due to shear and torsion forces too).

Comment: If the object wobbles, which equation is the field following?

Comment: @ÁlvaroRodrigo . The field follows the wave equation that you see in this answer. I would also say that it is the field $u$ on $S^2$ that wobbles not "the object" by which presumably you mean $S^2\,.$

Comment: @ÁlvaroRodrigo if you want to describe a wobbly object (like you see in a soccer ball after it is kicked), then it means you’re taking a smooth manifold $M$ ($S^2$ as an idealization of a soccer ball) and considering a time-dependent family of Riemannian metrics, $g_t$, on $M$. One could try to write down equations for $g_t$ in terms of other (time-dependent) tensor fields defined on $M$. I would search up for things like elasticity in Riemannian manifolds. But be warned that this stuff gets very hard very quickly. It’s best to study simple model problems in simple linearized situations.